# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'curr_cnt' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is the code:

```
def mostFrequent(num1,n):
    for i in range(1,n):
        if (num1[i] == num1[i-1]):
            curr_cnt += 1
        else :
            if (curr_cnt > max_cnt):
                max_cnt = curr_cnt
                res = num1[i-1]
                curr_cnt = 1
        if (curr_cnt > max_cnt):
            max_cnt = curr_cnt
            res = num1[n-1]
        return res

num1 = data['num1'].values
num1.sort()
n = len(num1);max_cnt = 1;res = num1[0];curr_cnt = 1

print(mostFrequent(num1, n))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Every line must have four additional spaces. You can also highlight your code text and press the code `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: You need to initialize all your variables before you can start using them. max_cnt is not available in `mostFrequent` function

Comment: curr_cnt this variable is not initialized. Please initialize it first

Comment: If you're using pandas, you can get the most frequent value by just `data['num1'].mode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some variables were initialized outside the `mostFrequent` function. They need to be available inside the function if they are to be used there. Here's how to fix this,

```
def mostFrequent(num1,n):
    max_cnt = 1
    res = num1[0]
    curr_cnt = 1
    for i in range(1,n):
```

Comment: Gracias, Amigo!

Comment: @LoV_a glad I could help. Please accept this answer (by clicking the check mark beside the answer) if it solved your issue. Thanks

Comment: @LoV_a please mark since question answered. Thanks.